# How do I test for a folder existing in Apple Script?

Tags: directory, applescript

I am trying to run "cd Desktop" in the terminal if the Desktop folder exists. Here is my current code:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    try
        if exists folder "Desktop" then
            do script "cd Desktop" in tab 1 of window 1
        end if
        do script "java -jar /Users/Harry/Desktop/Candle.app/Contents/candle.jar" in tab 1 of window 1
    on error
        if exists folder "Desktop" then
            do script "cd Desktop"
        end if
        do script "java -jar /Users/Harry/Desktop/Candle.app/Contents/candle.jar"
    end try
end tell
```

I am very new to apple script, so I don't know why this calls a syntax error when saved/compiled. Can anyone help??? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript is a fairly minimal language, and relies on other applications to perform stuff that it doesn't know about.

You are getting the error because **Terminal** doesn't know what the term `folder` is. Something like **Finder** or **System Events** can be used to handle file objects, and you can also coerce the path to an alias, which will error if it does not exist - note that your usage of the term `exists` in this case would be from the standard suite, which is for general objects, so it will return true since the string does exist.

Also note that each `do script` statement will be in its own window unless otherwise specified. I think you are looking for something more like:

```
set theFolder to "/Users/you/Desktop"
tell application "Finder" to set folderExists to exists (folder theFolder as POSIX file)
if folderExists then
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        try
            do script "cd Desktop" in tab 1 of window 1
        on error errmess
            log errmess
            do script "cd Desktop"
        end try
        delay 0.05
        do script "echo testing" in tab 1 of window 1
    end tell
else
    beep
end if
```

Comment: Ah I understand now! What is POSIX though?

Comment: POSIX paths, such as the one used in my example, are the Unix-y ones that use a slash as the delimiter, and are used by the Terminal  The Finder and several parts of the OS use HFS paths though, which use a colon as the delimiter and also include the volume name.  Depending on what you are using (the Finder only knows about HFS paths), a coercion may be needed between the two.